# Regex and config.json -file

Tags: regex, configuration

I am building an Angular application and trying to figure out the way to write ngsw-config.json -file in order to define rules for service worker.

I assumed that regex would be recognized as regex in configuration file and not interpret as normal characters / text automatically, but it was not so. I have for example following piece of a code:

```
"name": "authentication",
      "urls": [
        "/login",
        "/.*authentication.*"
      ],
```

part .* is not in my understanding recognized as regex (regex meaning in this case that any path that has text "authentication" would fall into this category, right?). This piece of a configuration tries to prevent service worker to take a lead in these two cases, it works with /login, but not with authentication part.

Question:
Can I somehow modify my file to make it recognize regex definitions?

Comment: Hi Samuel, can you please add more context so we can understand what your setup is, what the current vs expect outcome is? This is a code helping site, so please share as much as you can so we can reproduce your problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (a starting point would be read by what program/app in what language for what purpose and what is currently happening right now that doesnt match what you want?)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I added a bit of a context to my question now, hopefully it is clearer now what I'm asking and could help also someone else.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config
you can use a limited glob format.

I don't know what kind of url you want to match.

1. Option: If you want to match a url like `/foo/bar/authentication/foo2/bar2` you could use:

```
"name": "authentication",
      "urls": [
        "/login",
        "/**/authentication/**/*"
      ],
```

2. Option: If you want to match a url like `/foo/bar/something-authentication-otherthing/foo2/bar2` you could use:

```
"name": "authentication",
      "urls": [
        "/login",
        "/**/*authentication*/**/*"
      ],
```